# Wide-to-Long DataFrame Transpose

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transpose a dataframe from wide format to long format. I tried using pandas' `pd.wide_to_long`, but my column names are dynamic. I have a dataset that's currently formatted as follows:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1"    : {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
                   "2019-12" : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3))),
                   "2020-01" : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3))),
                   "2020-02" : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3)))
                  })
```

Original DataFrame

```
    col1    2019-12   2020-01   2020-02
0      a  -1.085631 -1.506295 -2.426679
1      b   0.997345 -0.578600 -0.428913
2      c   0.282978  1.651437  1.265936
```

Desired DataFrame

```
  col1  year  month     value
0    a  2019     12 -1.085631
1    b  2019     12  0.997345
2    c  2019     12  0.282978
3    a  2020      1 -1.506295
4    b  2020      1 -0.578600
5    c  2020      1  1.651437
6    a  2020      2 -2.426679
7    b  2020      2 -0.428913
8    c  2020      2  1.265936
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.melt` in your case and then just split the year-month:

```py
df = pd.melt(df, ['col1'], var_name='year')

df['month'] = df['year'].str.extract('-(\d+)')
df['year'] = df['year'].str.extract('(\d+)-')

Out[1]: 
  col1  year     value month
0    a  2019 -0.866740    12
1    b  2019 -0.678886    12
2    c  2019 -0.094709    12
3    a  2020  1.491390    01
4    b  2020 -0.638902    01
5    c  2020 -0.443982    01
6    a  2020 -0.434351    02
7    b  2020  2.205930    02
8    c  2020  2.186786    02
```

Answer (score 2):

Try pandas melt, convert the variable to a datetime and extract the month from it

```
(df.melt(id_vars='col1')
  .assign(month=lambda x:x.variable.astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.month,
          Year = lambda x: x.variable.astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.year)
  .drop('variable',axis=1)
)
```

**Update** : for future vistors - stacking can be beneficial here. the key is to split the columns and convert to a multiindex:

```
res = df.set_index('col1')
#convert to multiIndex
res.columns = res.columns.str.split('-',expand=True)
#give the levels in the multiindex names
res.columns = res.columns.set_names(['year','month'])

#stack columns and reset to get final output
res.stack([0,1]).reset_index(name='value')
```

With [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html), you can abstract the reshaping:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer(index="col1", 
                names_to=("year", "month"), 
                names_sep="-")
 
  col1  year month     value
0    a  2019    12 -1.085631
1    b  2019    12  0.997345
2    c  2019    12  0.282978
3    a  2020    01 -1.506295
4    b  2020    01 -0.578600
5    c  2020    01  1.651437
6    a  2020    02 -2.426679
7    b  2020    02 -0.428913
8    c  2020    02  1.265936
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set index and unstack. followed by `str.split` to expand year & month

```
long = df.set_index('col1').unstack().rename('value').reset_index()
long[['year', 'month']] = long.level_0.str.split('-', expand=True)
del long['level_0']

long
# outputs
  col1     value  year month
0    a -1.085631  2019    12
1    b  0.997345  2019    12
2    c  0.282978  2019    12
3    a -1.506295  2020    01
4    b -0.578600  2020    01
5    c  1.651437  2020    01
6    a -2.426679  2020    02
7    b -0.428913  2020    02
8    c  1.265936  2020    02
```